# Java Rectangle Intersect Method

Tags: java

In the code I have written, I am trying to determine when two Rectangle2D shapes have intersected. However when I run the code, the intersect method always returns true even when the shapes are clearly not. If anyone has any insight into this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

```
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
    FontRenderContext context = g2.getFontRenderContext();

    Rectangle2D rectangleOne = fontOne.getStringBounds(blockOne, context);
    Rectangle2D rectangleTwo= fontTwo.getStringBounds(blockTwo, context);

    if(rectangleOne.intersects(rectangleTwo)){ ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getStringBounds` method returns a logical bound. To obtain the Graphical bound, use [`TextLayout.getBounds`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/font/TextLayout.html#getBounds%28%29) instead.

Example:

```
Font font = Font.getFont("Helvetica-bold-italic");
FontRenderContext frc = g.getFontRenderContext();
TextLayout layout = new TextLayout("This is a string", font, frc);
```

Comment: How do I use the TextLayout.getBounds method? I imported the TextLayout package but I can't seem to figure out how to invoke the method.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer made me realize a major blunder I made.